# Adding target to a library with sublibraries added to it

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, libtool, libtool-xcode

I first created my project as static library(A) and added libs(B and C) to it. After some build setting fixes i was able to build Lib A successfully. ie it first generated libs for B and C.
  Now i have created a new target for Lib A and added libA.a in Link Binary With Libraries. But now if build my new target it directly tries to generate libs for A and since libs B,C are not yet created i am getting error libB.a not found.

Can someone tell what i may be missing or some build setting i need to add, so that libB,C is generated before libA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot integrate a static lib into a static lib. When you use your libA in a project, you have to add agains sub-libs that you've built with libA.